# How much of this large square is shaded blue?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

How it's made:
To make this figure, first, the left half of a large square was cut into two smaller blue squares each a quarter the area of the original large square. Then, to the right of both squares, there is a succession of blue squares, each one topped by a line that extends from the midpoint of the square to the left of it. How much of this large square is shaded blue?[image]

Comment: Can you please edit to show your attempt and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that every square is *one fourth* the area of the square directly to its left. So the total area of the blue squares can be found by adding all the areas of these squares individually:

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\text{Area}} &= \overbrace{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}}^{\text{Area of biggest squares}} + \overbrace{\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}}^{\text{Area of second biggest squares}} + \overbrace{\left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{4} +   \left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{4} }^{\text{Area of third biggest squares}}+ ...\\
& = 2\left[\frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 + ...\right] \tag{1}
\end{align*}

So now we want to find the value of $\color{blue}{\text{Area}}$. How do we do this? We proceed by multiplying equation $(1)$ on both sides by $\frac{1}{4}$. We get that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4}\color{blue}{\text{Area}} & =\frac{1}{4}\cdot  2\left[\frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 + ...\right]  = 2\left[ \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}  + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{4}...\right] \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where on the last equality we distibuted the $\frac{1}{4}$ to each term of the infinte sum. Lastly, we subtract equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$ and we get
\begin{align*}
&&\color{blue}{\text{Area}} - \frac{1}{4} \color{blue}{\text{Area}}  &= 2\left[\frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 + ...\right] - 2\left[ \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}  + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{4}...\right]\\
\implies& & \frac{3}{4} \color{blue}{\text{Area}}  &= 2 \left[ \frac{1}{4} + \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2} - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}}_{0} + \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3} - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}}_{0}+...\right]\\
\implies& &  \color{blue}{\text{Area}}  &= \frac{4}{3} \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} 
 = \boxed{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{align*}
and since the total area of large the square is $1$ unit, and $\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{1} = \frac{2}{3}$, we can conclude that the blue $\color{blue}{\text{Area}}$ is $\frac{2}{3}$ the area of the large square.

---

There's an important detail. The above procedure only works because $\frac{1}{4}< 1$, and hence we can say that the infinite sum $ \frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 + ...$ actually converges to some given value and doesn't grow to infinity. The above type of sum is known as a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), and you can check the given link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is evident the shaded area in $2/3$ because the upper shaded part, lower shaded part and unshaded part are all equal. So, one divided by $3$ is $1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

The area of the upper shaded part is the sum of a geometric series:

$$\tfrac14+(\tfrac14)^2+(\tfrac14)^3+...=\tfrac14 \tfrac{1}{1-\tfrac14}=\tfrac13$$

We have to multiply by 2 to have the whole blue area, giving the result:

$$A=\tfrac23$$